# Some isomorphism conditions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, category-theory

Here I want to ask some true or false problems regarding isomorphisms (and if false, is there some extra condition to make it true). I do not what is the correct title for these problem. And I also want some brief proofs if possible.

1. Let $R$ and $R'$ be two rings with $|R| =|R'|< \infty$. And each proper ideal in $R$ is isomorphic to some ideal in $R'$. Then is it true that $R\cong R'$? (and if false, is there some extra condition to make it true).
2. Let $G$ and $G'$ be two groups with the same order ($< \infty$). If their abelianizations are isomorphic, is it true that $G\cong G'$.
3. Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a subcategory of a category $\mathcal{C}$.
   (1) If $u$ is an isomorphism of $\mathcal{D}$, is $u$ an isomorphism of $\mathcal{C}$?
   (2) If $v$ is an isomorphism of $\mathcal{C}$, is $v$ an isomorphism of $\mathcal{D}$? 
   (and if false, is there some extra condition to make it true).

Comment: What does it mean for two ideals to be isomorphic?

Comment: 3. (1) is obviously true; (2) make $\mathcal{D}$ a full subcategory. 2. there are simple groups of the same order. It remains to answer 1, which I leave to the  algebraists after you clarified Qiaochu's question.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: I mean there exists ring homomorphisms $\psi: I\to I'$ and $\phi: I'\to I$ such that $\phi\circ\psi = id$ and $\psi\circ\phi = id$.

Comment: (1) is not true. take $R=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $R'=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. The only proper ideals of R are the zero ideal and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and they both appear in R'. Also, you might want to ask about proper subrings and not ideals (though it is still not true, but might be with extra conditions)

Comment: @ Theo Buehler: Sorry. I did not understand your explanation for Q2. I am not a algebraist (or trained to be) either. I hope my questions do make sense :-)

Comment: @user5980: what do you mean by a ring homomorphism between two ideals? (Is this a homomorphism of not necessarily unital rings, i.e. a rng homomorphism?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to #2 is no. For example, the dihedral group $D_4$ and the quaternion group $Q_8$ both have order $8$ and abelianization $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$. (This implies, among other things, that they have the same character table.) Group theory would be very boring if anything like this was true.